# Creating a view table/query in SQLite Android? What is its scope?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

So I wanted to make a query of a query but wasn't sure how to do this in Android SQLite.

I came across Views (not the Views in Android) but the Views in SQL, where it's sort of like a temporary table you can query.

If I am using this View to join together a bunch of tables and then I have a separate Cursor/query that queries that View, what's the correct setup?

Do I "create" the View in the onCreate function of the SQLiteOpenHelper class? Or do I create it only when I query it? What's the correct way here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SQLite `VIEWS` can be create in `SQLiteOpenHelper.onCreate()` after you create the tables referenced by the select statement.

The `CREATE VIEW` command assigns a name to a pre-packaged `SELECT` statement. Once the `VIEW` is created, it can be used in the `FROM` clause of another `SELECT` in place of a table name.

There's also an option of creating temporary `VIEWS` but I don't think this is what you need.